# WordPress: Can I use get_template_part in place of get_header, get_footer, etc?

Tags: wordpress, templates

Are there any potential issues with using get_template_part in place of get_header, get_footer, and get_sidebar.

I'd like to keep my theme folder organized and would be nice to move these pieces to the parts directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly legitimate. As you know, everything but index.php and style.css is optional.  Nicely addressed already at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16554/when-is-get-template-part-preferable-to-simply-using-the-template-php-files.

Comment: Looking through the source I did notice that there are hooks for get_header, get_footer and get_sidebar. But I'm not sure how prevalent their use is by plugins. Probably not very.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically, `get_header()` and `get_footer()` loads templates named `header.php` and `footer.php`.

Answer (score 0):

They are required functions. You would actually get errors in a dev enviroment if they are not there. Also those functions are heavilly hooked by other functions and plugins.

Comment: I don't seem to be getting any errors. But I don't typically use a lot of plugins. Mainly ACF and Formidable. I guess you could add back in the hooks at the start of your respective parts files.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L0) for `get_header()` and `get_footer()` you can see there isn't much going on besides calling the hook and loading the include. To preserve the hook and move your header template anywhere you want you could just define a custom get_header() function:

```
function custom_get_header($path) {
  do_action('get_header');
  get_template_part($path);
}
```

The Sage framework uses this approach for the header and footer, just without the wrapping function. [See source](https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/base.php).